# How to use both local db user & Azure Active Directory for authentication and authorization in ASP. NET Core

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal, azure-identity

**The Problem**

I am going to develop a web application using MVC .NET6. The requirement is that I need to use Asp.net core identity to authenticate users in the local database and from Azure Active Directory at the same time. The authorization part is simple there is no policy, role, or claim is required at the moment. I only need to use the `[Authorize]` attribute once the authentication is succeeded.

The UI login page would have a username/password and a login button to authenticate the user from the database. There will be another button like `Azure Sign In` for authentication from azure and redirects to the Microsoft page for credentials.

I've tried to find sample code or similar examples but couldn't find any.

Please help me to achieve this.

Thanks.